# Logging for JBoss 3.2.5 Java EE Client

Tags: logging, jakarta-ee, jboss, client

I am trying to find out why a Java EE client (stand alone Java program that uses jbossall-client.jar) is failing to connect to a Java EE Server so it would be good to enable logging that occurs from within JBoss AS classes such as `org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext` - presume there is a config file I can set up?

Just for info this is the actual exception that I am getting - hopefully logging would give a bit more info.

**Error**

```java
javax.naming.CommunicationException: 
    Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 
        Receive timed out]
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.discoverServer
            (NamingContext.java:1119)
```

Comment: are you trying to enable logging on the jboss server or your client through the jboss client jar?

Comment: Could you show the client code, especially the initialization of the `InitialContext` (if this is still an issue)?